# Views & Multi-dimensional table

Tags: views, theming

I have the following configuration with my drupal website:

- **Taxonomy vocabulary:** Procedure
- **Users Role:** Doctor
- **Node Type:** Surgical Operation

When I create a "Surgical Operation" node, I can select a procedure (abdominoplasty, breast augmentation, etc...) and a doctor (users with doctor role) via entities.

What I would like to do now is create a View that displays what operations have been performed, how many times, and by what doctors in a table:

[image: Table example]

So far I have tried the following modules without success:

- Views Aggregator Plus;
- Views Calc;
- Views Table Group;

How should I proceed? Should I create a module myself to display these informations?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem and I could solve it using [Views Matrix](https://drupal.org/project/views_matrix) module. It has only a dev version for Drupal 7, but it did the job perfectly.

Look at this question, it's almost the same except that I didn't need to count the items: [Matrix view with content as columns and taxonomy terms as rows](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91088/matrix-view-with-content-as-columns-and-taxonomy-terms-as-rows)

There is also another answer to that question which I tested and it works as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was able to create the table with "Views Matrix" and "Views Table Group" modules.

However, I can't find a way to display the total in the last row and the last column of the table, I think the only way is to create a custom module...

Comment: For what purpose did you used 'Views Table Group' module?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to add a sum of the columns at the end of the table using 'Views Matrix' module, since the other views plugins that provide this functionality are also using the display format.

Comment: There are 2 ways I can suggest you to go with, I'll update my answer.

Comment: But I have to work now, please remind me in 8 hours to update my answer with the suggestions. In short, I'll suggest you to use attachment display or using the template based answer to my problem instead of Views Matrix.

Comment: Views Table Group is pretty much doing the same than Views Matrix. I could achieve the same thing with both of them and then I got stuck at the same point. I thought about the attachment but I end up having 3 tables instead of one... I think I will go for the template based answer. Thank you for your help!